# Coordinates extracted from PDF are not exact

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text, geolocation, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

I'm working on rendering a georeferenced PDF within a map, I was able to retrieve the geolocation information from the PDF, but the coordinates I receive are not correct, they are a few meters apart from the places they really should be.

Opening the same PDF in Avenza Maps, it indicates this list of coordinates, and these are correct:

```
[-26.413082, -51.561534, -26.435838, -51.561643, -26.435909, -51.543773,-26.413152, -51.543667]
```

In the format I'm doing (reading the PDF as a String and doing a RegEx) I get these values:

```
[-26.43302 -51.56133 -26.41418 -51.56124 -26.41424 -51.54409 -26.43309 -51.54418]
[-26.45579 -51.59842 -26.41777 -51.59822 -26.41811 -51.51036 -26.45613 -51.51053]
```

But unfortunately none of the two reflect in the correct place (as in Avenza). That said, I opened the PDF in Notepad and found other values (more related to conversion and information), and I believe that maybe there is some way to convert the coordinates that I got through this other information, to the correct coordinates.

Follow the informations:

```
/VP [
    <<
        /Type
        /Viewport
        /BBox [14.1732 147.400915455 822.0456 1133.350548016]
        /Name (TSBII)
        /Measure <<
            /Type
            /Measure
            /Subtype
            /GEO
            /Bounds [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
            /GPTS [ -26.43302 -51.56133 -26.41418 -51.56124
                    -26.41424 -51.54409 -26.43309 -51.54418]
            /LPTS [ 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
            /GCS<<
                /Type
                /PROJCS
                /WKT (
PROJCS["SIRGAS_2000_UTM_Zone_22S",
    GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS_2000",
        DATUM["D_SIRGAS_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-51.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]
]
)
            >>
        >>
    >>
    <<
        /Type
        /Viewport
        /BBox [14.1732 14.1732 239.961243463 122.688692878]
        /Name (Referencia_Mapa)
        /Measure <<
            /Type
            /Measure
            /Subtype
            /GEO
            /Bounds [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
            /GPTS [ -26.45579 -51.59842 -26.41777 -51.59822
                    -26.41811 -51.51036 -26.45613 -51.51053]
            /LPTS [ 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
            /GCS<<
                /Type
                /PROJCS
                /WKT (
PROJCS["SIRGAS_2000_UTM_Zone_22S",
    GEOGCS["GCS_SIRGAS_2000",
        DATUM["D_SIRGAS_2000",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]
    ],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",10000000.0],
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-51.0],
    PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],
    UNIT["Meter",1.0]])
            >>
        >>
    >>
]
>>
```

How can I get the correct coordinates?

I realized that the map in the application I work in is in WGS84, but I still don't understand why the coordinates that I extract from the PDF are not aligned in the correct place, taking it from Avenza.